# How to implement the Postman get method in my html form

Tags: php, json, rest

Im very new to php programming and Im trying to create a rest api using this tutorial https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html
Everything works fine while using Postman, now I would like to insert the data via an html-form.

HTML code

```
<form action="##/object/addobject.php">
        <input type="text" name="id_group" value="" placeholder="id of the group">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="title">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP
thats the way the data is supposed to arrive in my file

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

What do I need to do for my code to use this url

```
localhost/../object/addobject.php?id_group=3&title=title&description=description
```

JSON

```
{"id_group" : 3 , "title" : "title" , "description" : "description"}
```

I've tried this

```
include "./header.php"; 

if(
    !empty($_GET['id_group']) &&
    !empty($_GET['title']) &&
    !empty($_GET['description'])
    ) {
        $url = urldecode('http://localhost/digitalestadt/object/addobject.php?' . $_GET['id_group'] . "&" . $_GET['title'] . "&" . $_GET['description']);

        $url_json = json_encode(file_get_contents($url));
    }
```

But it obviously didn't work

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You browser is not going to transform the data to json when sending it to the server. You would have to check the contents of `file_get_contents("php://input")` to see how you can use it. For example by using `json_decode()` on the input and if that does not return anything, you can set `$data = $_GET;`

Answer (score 0):

You should add get in your form

```
<form action="/object/addobject.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="id_group" value="" placeholder="id of the group">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" placeholder="title">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="description" value="" placeholder="description">
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

you can receive the GET params in your php file via

```
$_GET['id_group'];
```

Comment: I know that this works aswell, I'd like to keep the option of a json input. If you use $_GET the values wont be in json format